# Field's type base on it parent's type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm facing the following problem in Typescript:

```js
class PopulationDto<E> {
    path: keyof E;
    population?: PopulationDto<any>[];
}

class Building {
  floor: string;
  room: string;
}

class Address {
  building: Building;
  street: string;
  city: string;
}

class User {
  name: string;
  address: Address[];
}

const population: PopulationDto<User>[] = [
    { path: "address", population: [{ path: "building" }] },
];
```

I get type suggestion in the first `path` (`"address" | "name"`), and I also want the second one to suggest the corresponding type (`"building" | "street" | "city"`), but it doesn't work since the recursion type is `any`.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Will the generic type E always be set to User? Can it be one of the other types in your example?

Comment: No, E will be every other types

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQqnVw) might help you in the direction of your query (I made some broad assumptions about your types), but there's an intrinsic need for specifying more type detail in the annotation because its purpose is to constrain the shape of the value.